# How to save a Koala dataframe to ORC using ZLIB compression?

Tags: pyspark, spark-koalas

Koalas dataframes (the Pandas API to Spark) has a [to_orc](https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/api/databricks.koalas.DataFrame.to_orc.html) method to save in the ORC format.

How to call it telling it save compressed using the ZLIB method?

Comment: based on the doc, you can provide spark properties as a dict. so, my guess is `to_orc('path/path/name', {'compression': 'zlib'})`. also, spark has officially launched [Pandas API on Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/pandas_on_spark/index.html#pandas-api-on-spark). `koalas` is from databricks.

Comment: @samkart write it as an answer that I'll accept it.